# Tag Cleanup - February 2014

Tags: discussion, tags

The following tags, I feel, need to be removed; they do not add value to the questions being asked, usually because they are too broad. Feel free to edit this list and add more. **If you do not agree with tags listed here, add a comment or answer with your reasoning. We are a community, so that means we decide together as a group**.

What do we need from you, the user? Pick a list, and try to remove the tags from the questions. Report back here when you have completed a section. To not flood the front page, only do a few at a time. If all the questions of a tag have the tag removed, the system will prune the tags for us. If they are used again, we can also get some of them burninated. If you need help, feel free to post on this meta post.

- **DONE!** [freelance](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freelance) (14 questions)
- **DONE!** [client](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/client) (70 questions)
- **DONE!** [connection](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connection) (2 questions)
- **DONE!** [employment](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/employment) (5 questions)
- **DONE!** [freelance-fields](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freelance-fields) (5 questions)
- **DONE!** [approach](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/approach) (4 questions)
- **DONE!** [knowledge](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knowledge) (2 questions)
- **DONE!** [motivation](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motivation) (1 question)

-- Tags to Review --

- [legal](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) (30 questions). Can the Tag Wiki and Exert be cleaned up?

Comment: We should go through each tag and edit questions to clean them up, close/remove stuff that doesn't belong, etc. There isn't that many. We can remove the tag as we go through the list.

Comment: Sounds good to me! I'll set aside some time this weekend to start on these ones

Comment: `freelance` is a definite no-no. In fact, meta-tags are explicitly reserved for meta. (and "freelancing" is automatically blocked)

Comment: Since I can only suggest edits, I'll reference this question in the edit summary. Is that alright if I do that?

Comment: Also, [tag:motivation] is cleaned up.

Comment: @ChrisForrence Thank you for doing that, and yes, reference this question for Tag Cleanups

Comment: Employment is clean

Comment: Question about [this question](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1449): just having the [tag:portfolio] tag doesn't seem enough; since it's about a freelancer's site coming up for a client's site, I was tempted to tag with [tag:freelance-websites]. However, questions with that tag don't fit this as well. Ideas?

Comment: @Chris I think it's safe to use just portfolio on that one. Thanks

Comment: Freelance-fields is clean. Now for the big one...

Comment: Hey @ChrisForrence, one suggestion is to also look at titles. If they can be clarified, it helps improve SEO and the chances folks will click on them. Title edits are generally considered substantial since they have such a huge impact on attracting views from both SE searches as well as Google.

Comment: [tag:client] now has zero questions associated with it

Answer (score 3):

Once we're done going through this list, we should add [legal](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) to the list, not for *removal* but for review.

For our site to become a high quality resource of knowledge, it's important that legal answers be backed up with references and citations. If an answerer is an expert on the topic, then he/she should easily be able to find supporting information.

If we cannot commit to doing that as a community, we may need to review whether or not we should allow legal questions.

As an aside, we really need more community members involved in the moderation process for this site to succeed. **If you can't edit or retag, you can flag! :)**

## **What is a tag cleanup?**

***The most important aspect of the cleanup is to review the posts for quality. Removal of the tag is mostly ceremonial, since a Stack Exchange developer can simply run a query to remove the tags.***

These tags no longer serve a purpose (or arguably never did serve a purpose), so we plan to remove them. But this is an opportunity to go through the questions and answers and look over them. Do they look neat, professional? Do they need some editing? Is there anything we should remove, close, reopen, etc? In essence, we use the tag removal as a sort of checklist of what posts we've reviewed and left in a good state.

While the regular community may have moved on and forgotten about these posts, they are viewed daily by visitors coming from Google. Posts that represent the kind of quality and expert level material we strive for is what will keep people coming back for more.

**Note:** Tag cleanups can also take the form of reviews. For instance, many answers in the [legal](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) may need some editing to back up answers with citations or references, but the tag will not be removed.

---

### Community Involvement

**Which tags are the worst?**

The area where we need the most help with the tag cleanup is the [client](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/client) tag. There are 73 questions. If you can retag, please help out. If you can edit to fix problems with a post, that helps too. If there's a problem you can't fix, either flag the post or create a meta discussion.

Remember, the idea is to review the content and fix problems you see. Removing the tag is sort of an auxiliary goal.

For the [legal](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) tag, there are 30 questions. We should ask if the post needs the tag, and if it does, do the answers need references?  If so, we can either edit them, leave a comment, flag them for mod attention where we can either leave a comment ourselves, remove them if they're really bad, or add a "citation needed" post notice to the answer where we can come back to them later using a [special filter](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/search?q=hasnotice%3A1+is%3Aanswer+closed%3A0).